# what am i doing wrong I keep getting illegal start of experssion public static void intro(){ java replit

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, boolean

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            intro();
            int numcorrect = 0;
            int answer;
            System.out.println("Welcome to envoirnmental travia");
            System.out.println("What should you do when you want to throw your device away");
            System.out.println("1 throw it in the garbage");
            System.out.println("2 recyle it");
            System.out.println("3 do nothing");
            answer = input.nextInt();
            while (answer < 2 || answer > 2) {
                System.out.println("Please retry"); {
                    if (answer == 2)
                        System.out.println("correct");
                    numcorrect += 1;
                }
                System.out.println("Why is it unsafe to throw electronics in the garbage");
                System.out.println("1 because chemicals will get released that will harm the air and soil");
                System.out.println("2 Its not bad there will be no diffrence");
                System.out.println("3 Why do I care");
                answer = input.nextInt();
                while (answer < 1 || answer > 1) {
                    System.out.println("Please retry"); {
                        if (answer == 1)
                            System.out.println("correct");
                        numcorrect += 1;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Are all computers and electroninc devices bad for the envoirnment");
                    System.out.println("1 Yes");
                    System.out.println("2 kinda");
                    System.out.println("3 no because some devices help the envoirnment like the envirbot which helps with ocean pollution by cleaning the ocean from any metal plastic because it detects contamination and finds the source by swimming");
                    answer = input.nextInt();
                    while (answer < 3 || answer > 3) {
                        System.out.println("Please retry"); {
                            if (answer == 3)
                                System.out.println("correct");
                            numcorrect += 1;
                        }
                        int totalQuestions = 3;
                        double score = (100 * numcorrect) / totalQuestions;
                        System.out.println(" You scored " + score + "%");
                    }
                    public static void intro() {
                        System.out.println("Welcome to the facts about the envoirnment");
                        String Fact;
                        String answer;
                        boolean yn;
                        System.out.println("Enter a fact about the envoirnment");
                        Fact = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("You entered " + Fact);
                        System.out.println("Did you know there are aproximatly 50 miilon tons of waste every year Did you know this fact or not enter yes or no");
                        String[] Links = new String[8];
                        System.out.println("please visit these links for more info");
                        Links[1] = "https://www.ewaste1.com/what-is-e-waste/";
                        System.out.println(Links[1]);
                        Links[2] = "https://www.toronto.ca/services-payments/recycling-organics-garbage/electronic-waste/";
                        System.out.println(Links[2]);
                        Links[3] = "https://earth911.com/eco-tech/e-waste-why-you-should-recycle-electronics/";
                        System.out.println(Links[3]);
                        System.out.println("yes/no");
                        while (true) {
                            answer = input.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                            if (answer.equals("yes")) {
                                System.out.println("Congrats you know this fact");
                                yn = true;
                                break;
                            } else if (answer.equals("no")) {
                                System.out.println("Sorry you didn't know this fact at least you know now");
                                yn = false;
                                break;
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Please enter Yes or NO");
                                //My program represents environmental caring
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I keep getting error i described in title can anyone tell me why i cant figure it out everything else runs fine it is just if i do that class method it all goes wrong i just dont understand why if anyone at all can help me i would really appereciate it i tried adding extra clurly braces i have the intro() on top so that isnt a problem

Comment: Format your code (search for "online java formatter" if you don't have an IDE to do it for you). With correct indentation you'll see that you aren't closing your curly-brace blocks correctly. As a result, you're trying to start your method `intro` in the middle of your method `main`, and defining a method immediately inside another method is now allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was compilation error. Also, it is better to format your code before submitting on stack overflow so that it is easier for others to review.

2 closing curly bracket were missing. I have added them. you can try the below code .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    intro();
    int numcorrect = 0;
    int answer;
    System.out.println("Welcome to envoirnmental travia");
    System.out.println("What should you do when you want to throw your device away");
    System.out.println("1 throw it in the garbage");
    System.out.println("2 recyle it");
    System.out.println("3 do nothing");
    answer = input.nextInt();
    while (answer < 2 || answer > 2) {
      System.out.println("Please retry");
      {
        if (answer == 2)
          System.out.println("correct");
        numcorrect += 1;
      }
      System.out.println("Why is it unsafe to throw electronics in the garbage");
      System.out.println("1 because chemicals will get released that will harm the air and soil");
      System.out.println("2 Its not bad there will be no diffrence");
      System.out.println("3 Why do I care");
      answer = input.nextInt();
      while (answer < 1 || answer > 1) {
        System.out.println("Please retry");
        {
          if (answer == 1)
            System.out.println("correct");
          numcorrect += 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Are all computers and electroninc devices bad for the envoirnment");
        System.out.println("1 Yes");
        System.out.println("2 kinda");
        System.out.println(
            "3 no because some devices help the envoirnment like the envirbot which helps with ocean pollution by cleaning the ocean from any metal plastic because it detects contamination and finds the source by swimming");
        answer = input.nextInt();
        while (answer < 3 || answer > 3) {
          System.out.println("Please retry");
          {
            if (answer == 3)
              System.out.println("correct");
            numcorrect += 1;
          }
          int totalQuestions = 3;
          double score = (100 * numcorrect) / totalQuestions;
          System.out.println(" You scored " + score + "%");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void intro() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the facts about the envoirnment");
    String Fact;
    String answer;
    boolean yn;
    System.out.println("Enter a fact about the envoirnment");
    Fact = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered " + Fact);
    System.out.println(
        "Did you know there are aproximatly 50 miilon tons of waste every year Did you know this fact or not enter yes or no");
    String[] Links = new String[8];
    System.out.println("please visit these links for more info");
    Links[1] = "https://www.ewaste1.com/what-is-e-waste/";
    System.out.println(Links[1]);
    Links[2] =
        "https://www.toronto.ca/services-payments/recycling-organics-garbage/electronic-waste/";
    System.out.println(Links[2]);
    Links[3] = "https://earth911.com/eco-tech/e-waste-why-you-should-recycle-electronics/";
    System.out.println(Links[3]);
    System.out.println("yes/no");
    while (true) {
      answer = input.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
      if (answer.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Congrats you know this fact");
        yn = true;
        break;
      } else if (answer.equals("no")) {
        System.out.println("Sorry you didn't know this fact at least you know now");
        yn = false;
        break;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter Yes or NO");
        // My program represents environmental caring
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my program stops midway